# In-app paymnt methods

Tags: software-center, application-development, android, bitcoin

I'm interested in developing for Ubuntu (mostly phones) and I can't seem to find the guidelines on app publishing, will apps only work through the ubuntu software center, or can users download and install an app from a website like is possible with an android apk?

Also, are there any rules regarding in-app purchase methods, (I hope the minimum price here isn't $2.99 in-app as well or I'm not going to even bother developing for Ubuntu and will just stick with Android) Google for example, requires that in-app purchases go through their servers so that it isn't possible to use other funding methods at least for play store published apps. My main questions here are: Would it be possible to release an app for ubuntu touch that accepted bitcoin, paypal, or other methods for in-app purchases? If not, would it be possible to release apps through a personal website or 3rd party app market that could use alternative payment methods?

Comment: Would you mind filing a new question for in-app purchasing? The way askubuntu works is that there is only one question at a time, so that it can be clearly answered and it stays focused on one single topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will find all the information about publishing apps on the developer site at http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

In essence, you create a click package with the Ubuntu SDK (via the Packaging tab in Qt Creator) and then you upload it to myapps.ubuntu.com. Once your package has gone through review and it's published, it will be available instantly via the Apps scope on the phone.

There is an ongoing discussion about making the apps available and installable from an online site, but such feature is not there yet.